Passing parameters in Quarto from Python to Typst or from Typst to Python
I need to create a few sections in a loop. Is there any way to pass _ as index to Python part, or increment Python ix variable inside the Typst loop?
​```{python}
​ix = 0
​```
​
​```{=typst}
​#for _ in range(`{python} len(tables)`) {
​    [
​       `{python} tables[ix]`
​    ]
​}
​```

